# How to detect the current viewport's timeframe?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Not just that it's below hour-level (`timeframe.isminutes` and `timeframe.multiplier < 60` stuff) but the actual current timeframe itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the built-in variable `timeframe.period`.

Comment: Perfect. :) Would you please look at the V5 VWAP question? It's so much key important to me and perhaps to anyone since the release of V5 Pine Script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081498/whats-the-v5-upgraded-form-of-the-classic-built-in-vwap-indicator

I'm just trying to upgrade it myself but already stuck at pow(src,2). Can't even find what's this, to be able to find its V5-compliant form. ta.pow() doesn work.

Comment: Wow, I finally got through and managed to upgrade the whole VWAP to V5, and it plots the same. Only a yellow warning returned which I am going to post a question about but it's already functional. Sorry for the false alarm, it seems I'm more clever than I usually think if I put efforts into…

Comment: Here's that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087799/timechange-function-returns-with-a-yellow-warning-what-does-it-mean-or-simply Sorry for flooding you. :)